# Partitions reference

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, integer-partitions

In [this paper](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/HLAlder.pdf), the author mentions before Theorem 23 that the result was proven by Elmo Moore in 1968; the associated reference says "unpublished result". I would be grateful to anyone who knows a reference to the result (or simply a proof thereof).

For reference, this theorem reads:

Let $p_1(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into parts which are either divisible by $4$ or odd. Let $q_1(n)$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ of the form $n_1+n_2+\cdots + n_s$, where $n_i\ge n_{i+1}$ and, if $n_i$ is odd, $n_i-n_{i+1}\ge 1$ for $1\le i\le s$. Then $p_1(n) = q_1(n)$.

Comment: I don't believe this is in any of Moore's four works indexed in MR, at least not in this form.  (Admittedly, I could not see the 1977 Bull. Calcutta Math. Soc. paper online, but the MR0558232 summary does not sound like it would include this result.)